# Calculate Sum on One Field Within Several Different Point Feature Classes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, modelbuilder, point

I have several point feature classes (eg: the location of mall, liquor stores, etc), that I need to get the count of within a specified city district. Basically, I want to great a modelbuilder model that calculates how many liquor stores and malls there are per city district.

I have already created a spatial join between the points and the polygon (which create separate output tables), but need to collapse them so I may do this tabulation. I have tried a bunch of different things but all of them don't allow you to count by polygon.

If you can point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Have you tried Merging your points together? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000

Comment: Assuming you have an attribute that indicates what type the point is (e.g. 1 = liquor store, 2 = mall etc..) then use Summary Statistics to compile the data. Select Count of OBJECTID and case of TYPE and DISTRICT (from polygon).

Comment: I think the issue is that these are in separate point feature classes. Merge, then Summary Stats.

Comment: Or @phloem, multiple summary stats then merge. Add a unique field first (like CLASS) to each feature class and calc to the feature type (e.g. 1 = liquor store, 2 = mall etc..) such that there is an integer identifying the type that can be referred to (join) or summarized on.

Comment: I am not sure if this messes things up, but I was trying to use a list within Modelbuilder so that all files would execute rather than doing them separately. However, I had the issue that when I attempted to merge, only the first feature class would select and the other points would not merge.

Comment: At the moment no answer has been offered to your question and I suspect the best way forward for you may be to **edit** this question to focus it on just getting the Merge part to work.  You can always come back to the remainder of what you are trying to do in a subsequent question.  Also, in any ModelBuilder question, I think it is best to include a picture of a test model that illustrates the part that is causing you problems.